# Searching Twitter with OAuth

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, access-token

Okay so I get an access token for Twitter each time I run my program...(It's tedious at the moment but I will find out how to make it a persistent store)... How do I go about using this access token so that when I search, I won't get a

> "Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour."
>    error?

It happens when I'm searching for the following: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=[screenName]"
Which is coded as :

```
BufferedReader ff = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ffUser.openConnection().getInputStream()));
```

In my code below:

```
public class UDC  {
private static String term1;
private static String term2;
public static String PIN;

private static final String twitterSearch = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23";
private static String rppPage = "&rpp=500&page=1";

private static final String ffGet = "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=";
private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "K7el7Fqu7UtcJv3A3ssOQ";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "w7ZX27ys58mafLYeivuA2POVe0gjhTIIUH26f2IM";

private static String entities = "&include_entities=true";

static Object[][] tableData = new Object[500][6];
static SearchResultC s = new SearchResultC();
static StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
static StringBuffer buff1 = new StringBuffer();

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{
    verifyURL v = new verifyURL();
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
      twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
      RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
      AccessToken accessToken = null; // = loadAccessToken(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            //Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance);
            //twitter.setOAuthConsumerKey(COMSUMER_KEY, COMSUMER_SECRET);
            //twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

      v.valURLText.setText(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
      v.vFrame.setVisible(true);
      int p = 0;

      do {
          //nothing
      } while (v.vFrame.isVisible());
                try {
                  if (PIN.length() > 0) {
                      accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, PIN);
                  } else {
                      accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
                  }
              } catch (TwitterException te) {
                  if(401 == te.getStatusCode()) {
                      showErrorPane("Unable to get access code", "Error");
                      p = 1;
                  } else {
                      te.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }

      //storeAccessToken(twitter.verifyCredentials().getId(), accessToken);


    if (p == 0) {
        initComponents();
        UDTFrame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "static-access"})
private static void searchButtonMouseClicked(String t1, String t2) throws IOException {

    if(t1.equals("") || t2.equals("") || t1.equals(t2))
        {
        showErrorPane("Invalid Search Terms", "Search Error");
    }

    else 
    {
        s.getInitComponents();
        clicked(t1, 0);
        clicked(t2, 3);
        s.SRTFrame.setVisible(true);
        s.sTerm1Field.setText(t1);
        s.sTerm2Field.setText(t2);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static void clicked(String term, int t){
    UDTFrame.setVisible(false);
    float follower;
    float friends;
    float ffRatio;
    float DUA;
    int statuses;
    int day;
    int year;
    String month;

    try {
        URL searchURL1 = new URL (twitterSearch + term + rppPage);
        //String searchURL = new String (twitterSearch + term + rppPage);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(searchURL1.openConnection().getInputStream()));

        //OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, searchURL);

        int c;
        while ((c=br.read()) != -1) {
            buff.append((char)c);
        }
        br.close();

        /*******************************************************************************************/
        /*******************************************************************************************/
        /******************************** follower/friend ratio ************************************/
        /*******************************************************************************************/
        /*******************************************************************************************/
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(buff.toString());
        JSONArray tweets = js.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject tweet = new JSONObject();
        for(int i=0; i < tweets.length(); i++) {
            tweet = tweets.getJSONObject(i);
            //System.out.println(tweet);
            //user[i] = tweet.getString("from_user_name");
            //System.out.println(tweet.getString("from_user_name"));
            //System.out.println(user[i]);
            String userName = tweet.getString("from_user");

            //URL ffUser = new URL(ffGet + user[i] + entities);
            URL ffUser = new URL(ffGet + userName + entities);
            String ffUser1 = new String(ffGet + userName + entities);

            BufferedReader ff = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(ffUser.openConnection().getInputStream()));
            OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, ffUser1);

            int d, e = 0;
            while((d = ff.read()) != -1) {
                buff1.append((char)d);
                e++;
            }
            ff.close();

            JSONObject js1 = new JSONObject(buff1.toString());
            //System.out.println(js1);
            //JSONArray userData = new JSONArray(buff1.toString());
            //JSONObject userData1;
            //for(int j = 0; j < js1.length(); i++){
                //userData1 = userData.getJSONObject(j);
                follower =  js1.getInt("followers_count");
                friends = js1.getInt("friends_count");
                ffRatio = friends/follower;

                String createdDate = js1.getString("created_at");
                statuses = js1.getInt("statuses_count");

                String nameData = js1.getString("name");
                String gen = gender(nameData);


        //}

    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

I'm completely new to this OAuth and Access Tokens and all so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing some things with Scribe and some things with Twitter4J? That's no good sign... Also you should edit your question to only contain the *relevant* parts of your code.

Comment: I was trying scribe at first but I couldn't get it working so I tried twitter4j... guess I must've mixed up the libraries :/

Answer (score 0):

With

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, ffUser1);
```

you are doing an unauthenticated request using the Scribe library (you never instantiated an `OAuthService` object which would have to be used to [sign](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java) this request). So when you do this too often Twitter denies these requests.

So your problem here does indeed come from mixing Twitter4J and Scribe.

Comment: Mmm okay... since I already got twitter4j's access token, how do I search "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=" with the access token? I tried googling it but all I got were examples of updating their tweets... or is that what twitter4j is for?

Comment: Why not [check their documentation](http://twitter4j.org/en/api-support.html)? There you would find the [`showUser(String screenName)`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html#showUser%28java.lang.String%29) method.